# FilePath is wrong/not supported

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

i´m trying to save a Camera Picture to a folder. When i save it, i become the following message:

"System.NotSupportedException: "The specified path format is not supported."

When i change the Filepath to be just one single string, the saving works fine, but i want a FileName, which is variable.

Maybe i´m just missing something or i am really dumb, but i really dont know what else i can do, heres the Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
        string[] paths = {@"D:\", stamp, ".jpg"};
        string fullpath = Path.Combine(paths);
        if (isCameraRunning)
        {
            Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            snapshot.Save(fullpath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Die Kamera konnte kein Bild machen, da die Kamera kein Bild aufnimmt","Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `G` format specifier for `DateTime` uses `:` to separate the hours, minutes and seconds, and you then use this as the file name. Since paths cannot contain `:` (except as part of the drive letter indicator), you get an exception as your file name is invalid.

(Separately, `Path.Combine()` is used for combining *paths*, it does not support constructing a file name out of the name and extension, e.g. `Path.Combine(new[] { "foo", ".bar" })` results in `foo\.bar`, *not* `foo.bar`).

Comment: Thank you Iridium, that was the Problem. After i manually changed the format of the Date/Time, the saving works now as intened. And thanks for the advice with the `Path.Combine()`, i have now changed it to the following:   `snapshot.Save(@"D:\" + stamp + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); `